# Why does my neural network trained on MNIST data set not predict 7 and 9 correctly?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, image-recognition, mnist

I'm using Matlab (  [github code repository](https://github.com/khannasarthak/Digit-Recognition-using-Neural-Networks) ). The details of the network are:

- Hidden units: 100 ( variable )
- Epochs : 500
- Batch size: 100

The weights are being updated using Back propagation algorithm.

I've been able to recognize 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8 which I have drawn in photoshop.

However 7,9 are not recognized, but upon running on the test set I get only 749/10000 wrong and it correctly classifies 9251/10000.

Any idea what might be wrong? Because it is learning and based on the test set results its learning correctly.

Comment: The asnwer: LOTS of things can be wrong. For example: if you train your NN without using 9s, then it will be bad detecting 9s. If all the 9s look similar in the training and then there are very different 9s in the tests then bad. Maybe your NN is not complex enough. etc, etc etc

Comment: What does it detect a `7`? a `2`? An idea is try to add those not detectable samples into your training set and let your NN experience new features.

Comment: It detects everything except 7 and 9. And i've trained it on the MNIST data set, which contains 9 and 7. Im assuming that MNIST contains proper representations of 7 and 9. And the ones that im trying to detect have been drawn properly.

 [seven](https://github.com/khannasarthak/Digit-Recognition-using-Neural-Networks/blob/master/Digit%20Recognition%20MNIST/Images/seven.jpg)

[nine](https://github.com/khannasarthak/Digit-Recognition-using-Neural-Networks/blob/master/Digit%20Recognition%20MNIST/Images/nine1.jpg)

Comment: when you say 7 and 9 are not recognized, does it mean that all 749 errors corresponds to 7 and 9? OR do you mean that they do not have a feature vector associated with them? OR?

Comment: @GameOfThrows no the errors are random, not only 7 and 9 but contain others numbers as well. But when i make my own 7 and 9 in photoshop and try to pass it through the network, they aren't recognized correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything downright incorrect in your code, but there is a lot that can be improved:

1. You use this to set the initial weights:

   ```
   hiddenWeights = rand(hiddenUnits,inputVectorSize);
   outputWeights = rand(outputVectorSize,hiddenUnits);

   hiddenWeights = hiddenWeights./size(hiddenWeights, 2);
   outputWeights = outputWeights./size(outputWeights, 2);
   ```

   This will make your weights very small I think. Not only that, but you will have no negative values, so you'll throw away half of the sigmoid's range of values. I suggest you try:

   ```
   weights = 2*rand(x, y) - 1
   ```

   Which will generate random numbers in `[-1, 1]`. You can then try dividing this interval to get smaller weights (try dividing by the sqrt of the size).
2. You use this as the output delta:

   ```
   outputDelta = dactivation(outputActualInput).*(outputVector - targetVector) % (tk-yk)*f'(yin)
   ```

   Multiplying by the derivative is done if you use the square loss function. For log loss (which is usually the one used in classification), you should have just `outputVector - targetVector`. It might not make that big of a difference, but you might want to try.
3. You say in the comments that the network doesn't detect your own sevens and nines. This can suggest overfitting on the MNIST data. To address this, you'll need to add some form of regularization to your network: either weight decay or dropout.
4. You should try different learning rates as well, if you haven't already.
5. You don't seem to have any bias neurons. Each layer, except the output layer, should have a neuron that only returns the value `1` to the next layer. You can implement this by adding another feature to your input data that is always `1`.

MNIST is a big data set for which better algorithms are still being researched. Your networks is very basic, small, with no regularization, no bias neurons and no improvements to classic gradient descent. It's not surprising that it's not working too well: you'll likely need a more complex network for better results.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I'm still a newbie in neural nets, this being my first implementation. I'll try incorporating what you have said into my code. Any particular resource that I might use to further my learning?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with neural nets or your code,
but this picture of KNN-nearest digits shows that some MNIST digits
are simply hard to recognize:

[image]